# Doctrine 2 delete has no effect

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have this:

```
$this->getDI()['entityManager']->getConnection()->delete('flakk', array('profile_id' => 2));
```

this has no effect, that record remains. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the return of the methods.  It should return the number of the rows affected

Comment: Maybe you should add `flush();`?

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine operations will not be persisted to database until you call `flush();`

May I suggest to do some reading in the documents on using doctrine before asking questions on stack**overflow**, because these things are all written **[in the documents](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#working-with-objects)**:

> It is very important to understand that only `EntityManager#flush()` ever causes write operations against the database to be executed. Any other methods such as `EntityManager#persist($entity)` or `EntityManager#remove($entity)` only notify the `UnitOfWork` to perform these operations during flush.
>   Not calling `EntityManager#flush()` will lead to all changes during that request being lost.